Can I get factors in a data frame from values that are lists?
I have a variety of descriptors for each row. I'd like to make them factors.
data <- data.frame(
  type = factor(c("sticky, warm", "ugly, matte", "warm, glittery", "ugly, glittery") )
)

This setup yields:
> data$type
Levels: sticky, warm ugly, glittery ugly, matte warm, glittery

But I would like it to be:
> data$type
Levels: sticky warm ugly glittery matte

I've tried using strsplit() to make the values lists before using factor() but that doesn't help.
One solution is to create multiple boolean columns for each descriptor but I was hoping for a something more elegant.

You cannot have factor levels that don't match strings in the data exactly. (Of course, you can have extra levels, but it's not the point.) Strings that don't correspond to any level will become NA. A solution for your case depends on what you want to do with your data.

You can create list column for factors and use all 5 levels for all lists.
How useful this is depends mostly on what you plan use it for. For example data.frame and tibble print methods will not show you level labels in such structure and filtering / subsetting becomes bit more verbose. And if you actually need factors at some point in your workflow, you probably need to reshape that frame.
Anyway,
data <- data2 <- data.frame(
  type = factor(c("sticky, warm", "ugly, matte", "warm, glittery", "ugly, glittery") )
)

# from factors to list column of strings
data$str_lst <- 
  as.character(data$type) |> strsplit(", ")

# build a vector of level labels
desc_levels <- 
  unlist(data$str_lst) |> unique() |> sort()

# from list column of strings to list column of factors
data$fct_lst <- 
  lapply(data$str_lst, factor, levels = desc_levels)

data
#>             type        str_lst fct_lst
#> 1   sticky, warm   sticky, warm    3, 5
#> 2    ugly, matte    ugly, matte    4, 2
#> 3 warm, glittery warm, glittery    5, 1
#> 4 ugly, glittery ugly, glittery    4, 1

str(data)
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ type   : Factor w/ 4 levels "sticky, warm",..: 1 3 4 2
#>  $ str_lst:List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr  "sticky" "warm"
#>   ..$ : chr  "ugly" "matte"
#>   ..$ : chr  "warm" "glittery"
#>   ..$ : chr  "ugly" "glittery"
#>  $ fct_lst:List of 4
#>   ..$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "glittery","matte",..: 3 5
#>   ..$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "glittery","matte",..: 4 2
#>   ..$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "glittery","matte",..: 5 1
#>   ..$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "glittery","matte",..: 4 1

str(desc_levels)
#>  chr [1:5] "glittery" "matte" "sticky" "ugly" "warm"

# subset by factor level:
subset(data, sapply(fct_lst, \(x) any(x == "warm")))
#>             type        str_lst fct_lst
#> 1   sticky, warm   sticky, warm    3, 5
#> 3 warm, glittery warm, glittery    5, 1

Or with dplyr & purrr:
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)

data2 |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(str_lst = as.character(type) |> strsplit( ", ")) |> 
  mutate(
    fct_lst = map(
      str_lst, 
      \(x, levels) factor(x, levels = levels), 
      levels = unlist(str_lst) |> unique() |> sort()
    )
  ) |> 
  # rowwise for bit less verbose filtering 
  rowwise() |> 
  filter(any(fct_lst == "warm")) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  print() |> 
  glimpse() 
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   type           str_lst   fct_lst  
#>   <fct>          <list>    <list>   
#> 1 sticky, warm   <chr [2]> <fct [2]>
#> 2 warm, glittery <chr [2]> <fct [2]>

#> Rows: 2
#> Columns: 3
#> $ type    <fct> "sticky, warm", "warm, glittery"
#> $ str_lst <list> <"sticky", "warm">, <"warm", "glittery">
#> $ fct_lst <list> <sticky, warm>, <warm, glittery>


